# Vue JS for updating checkboxes based on radio selection

Tags: checkbox, vue.js

I basically have the same question as [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37098506/populating-checkboxes-based-on-dropdown-value-selection), but using Vue JS instead of jQuery.

I have a list of N groups bound to my array `ensemble_groups` and represented by radio buttons. Selected value is mapped to `selected_group`.

I have a list of actors bound to my array `cast` with the variables `actor_id`, `actor_name` and `groups`. Each actor is pre-assigned to any number of groups. They're represented by checkboxes and mapped to an array `visible_actors` (when checked).

Here's my Vue JS powering the above data (I imagine the method is all jacked up, and I probably need a computed property of some sort):

```
new Vue({
    el: '#schedule-builder',

    data: {
      selected_group: 'Entire Cast',
      visible_actors: [],

      ensemble_groups: [
        "Entire Cast",
        "Leads",
        "Dancers",
        "Children",
        "Deselect All",
      ],

      cast: [
        {
          actor_id: "123",
          actor_name: "Carl",
          groups: ["Entire Cast","Leads",],
        },
        {
          actor_id: "234",
          actor_name: "Max",
          groups: ["Entire Cast","Leads","Children",],
        },
        {
          actor_id: "345",
          actor_name: "Sheryl",
          groups: ["Entire Cast","Dancers",],
        },
        {
          actor_id: "456",
          actor_name: "Chip",
          groups: ["Entire Cast","Children",],
        },
      ],
    },
    methods: {
      selectGroup: function() {
        // uncheck all
        visible_actors=[];
        // add people in this group to visible_actors
        for person in cast {
          if (person.groups.indexOf(selected_group) > -1) {
            visible_actors.push(person.actor_id);
          }
        }
    }
})
```

When a user clicks on a radio button for a group, I want to select only the actors' checkboxes who are in that group. So if the user selects "Children", only the actors in the "Children" group should be checked (Max and Chip, per my example).

And, obviously, checking an actor (rather than a group) shouldn't affect the rest of the selections. I mention this because I got it partially working at one point, where selecting a group also selected the correct people, but when I clicked on a person suddenly everyone else was deselected. User can click either a group OR a person, and the expected behavior is that

Here's my HTML template:

```
<div id="schedule-builder">
  <div class="select-groups">
    <h3>Ensemble Groups</h3>
    <template v-for="group in ensemble_groups">
      <input name="select_group[]" id="group_@{{ $index }}"
             v-model="selected_group"
             :value="group"
             @click="selectGroup"
             type="radio">
      <label for="group_@{{ $index }}">@{{ group }}</label>
    </template>
  </div>

  <div class="select-individuals">
    <h3>Cast Members</h3>
    <template v-for="person in cast">
      <input name="actors[]" id="actor-@{{ $index }}"
             v-model="visible_actors"
             :value="person.actor_id"
             :checked="visible_actors.indexOf(person.actor_id) > -1"
             type="checkbox">
      <label for="actor-@{{ $index }}">
        @{{ person.actor_name }}
      </label>
    </template>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated... I've been banging my head on it for a couple days already.

Comment: When you change the group should all selected characters only be part of that group?

Comment: Yes! So if a user selects a group, then checks an extra person, then clicks another group, ALL selections should be removed except the most recently selected group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tough question to answer well but I'll try.

I would not rely on a computed property for the checked state. Let `v-model` handle that for you. You can do

```
<input 
  type="checkbox" 
  name="actors[]" 
  v-model="selected_actors" 
  :value="actor">
```

and that will manage the array of `selected_actors` for you as their values change.

I'm at work and plan on elaborating on this answer a little later but here's a fiddle of how I'd approach the situation: https://jsfiddle.net/crswll/806shzzg/7/

Comment: Thank you, I'm still working on this problem and I'm making some headway on my third day of head banging. I've nixed the selected_actors` array in favor of a `checked` variable for each actor. It's all working now except the Group selector. I don't know enough JS I guess to write the proper method that will clear all the actor checkboxes and then check the actors whose groups contain the `selected_group`. https://jsfiddle.net/f48njuvb/

Comment: I think this is what you want https://jsfiddle.net/crswll/f48njuvb/2/ if you do, in fact, want the `checked` property on each actor. If you're using this list in other areas it could get a little tricky though since now checked will be all over the place.

Comment: This is perfect! I may rename the variable just to be a little less repetitive, but this method is magical! I was so close.... I was trying to do each() and needed to do forEach().... plus a couple other things related to syntax. Thanks!!!